# SQL regex FIND & Replace everything before a word, phrase, or path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using sql server mgmt studio. I'm trying to do an UPDATE query along with a REPLACE using a regex to strip off internal pathing. It doesn't seem to be working right. Is there some other way I need to be invoking regex in SQL?

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET Path = REPLACE(Path , '.+?(?=Data)', '')
```

I wanted to basically go from

`\\somepath\anotherpath\Data\file.txt` to `Data\File.txt`

There is going to be variations on the paths so I'm trying to use regex to remove all characters before the word `Data\`

My regular expression is "+?(?=Data)" which seems to be working find in Textpad, but not in SQL.

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you give some feed back?

Answer (score 0):

There is no regexp support in SQL server. This can be done using `substring` and `charindex` functions.

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET Path = 'Data\' + SUBSTRING(path,CHARINDEX('\Data\',path)+len('\Data\'),len(path))
WHERE CHARINDEX('\Data\',path) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reverse` and `charindex` to do this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET    path = 
       case when path like '%\\%\\%'
           then substr(path, 1-charindex('\\', reverse(path),
                                         charindex('\\', reverse(path))+1
                                        )
                     )
           else path
       end
```

This will find the second-last backslash, and take the characters that follow it. The `case when` is there to deal with paths that contain fewer than two backslashes.